# react.js - why rendering two times

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, console.log

I am trying to get a value from an array. The problem is value is rendering two times. 1st time gets undefined value but 2nd time seems like okay. Where I missed? [Please see the console result in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwpw8.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "./axios";
import ZingChart from "zingchart-react";

export default class Chart extends Component {
  state = {
    info: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/3r-elementor-timeline-widget.json/`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ info: res.data });
      });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      config: {
        type: "bar",
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    var values;
    const pluginInfo = this.state.info;
    if (pluginInfo !== undefined) {
      const ratings = Object.values(pluginInfo.ratings);
      values = ratings;
    }
    //var mySeries = [{ values: [1, 3, 8] }];
    var mySeries = [{ values: values }];
    console.log(mySeries); // 1st time get undefined array but 2nd time is ok. 

    return (
      <div>
        <ZingChart data={this.state.config} series={mySeries} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a myriad of issues going on in here, two main ones resulting in your problem are:

1. You set the default state using a class property, and then immediately wipe it out in the class constructor (this in effect means the default state of `info` is `undefined`).
2. You set `values` to `undefined` by default on each render, when the component first renders `this.state.info` is `undefined` therefore `values` remains `undefined` and you proceed to set this in `mySeries` which is then subsequently rendered in the UI.

If you don't want to render before you have something, render a placeholder Component instead e.g.

```
if (!values) return <p>Loading...</p>;

return (...) // render component with mySeries etc.
```

Comment: Okay. I accepted. Thank you for your cooperation. You are a awesome stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it renders the component then goes into `componentDidMount` and calls your axios function which is an async request. It then resolves the async request after x amount of time and sets the state which triggers a re-render.

Therefore it renders twice.

You are only setting values if pluginInfo is defined which it is on the second render.